# Geodesic equation and Lie derivation problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, metric-tensor, vector-fields, geodesics

I have a metric:
$$g_{ab}=\text{diag}(-1,a(t)^2,r^2,r^2 \sin^2(\theta))$$ where $$a(t)^2=\frac{3}{B}\cosh^2(\sqrt{\frac{3}{B}}t)$$ where $B$ is constant.

Also a tangent vector given: $$k^\mu=(a(t)^{-1},a(t)^{-2},0,0).$$
The problem is that I need to show that this tangent vector is geodesic of this spacetime.

My way is to solve it: I tried to calculate the Lie derivative of the metric along the vector space and I ended up :
$2 a(t)’(a(t)^{-2}-a(t)^{-1}+1)$ which doesn’t look zero. I re calculated few time and got the same result. Could someone help me or gives some hint?

Comment: I did a huge calculation mistakes all the time, but I found out.